# In VLOOKUP, if I get an error, I want to do another search using a different search value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have several similar, but not exact, names in a worksheet in subsequent rows. They all refer to the same "item". In creating a VLOOKUP, if I receive an error I want to do another VLOOKUP using an different, similar value across the same table array. I'm using

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!A:AZ,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(C1,Sheet1!A:AZ,2,FALSE))
```

I've tried many variations without any luck.

Comment: That's exactly how it is done. Are you saying that the second VLOOKUP should find a value and it isn't?

Comment: Are you sure the first VLOOKUP() is returning an error.  What result do you get when you put that function call into a separate cell?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula has the correct format to try finding B1 in column A of Sheet1 and, if it can't find anything, then try finding C1 in column A of Sheet1 instead. If it can't find C1 either, then it will still return an error.

If you have a value in B1 or C1 that you expect to be found in column A of Sheet1 but the formula is returning an error, you'll need to check some common vlookup issues:

1. The value isn't an exact match (even an extra space will cause a mismatch)
2. The value of B1 or C1 is being found, but the vlookup value from column B in Sheet1 has an error value and it's actually that error value being returned (rather than being any issue with the vlookup itself)
3. The value your searching for isn't in column A. (If you're only looking up the 2nd column in the lookup range, i.e. Column B, why do you include all columns from A to AZ in the lookup table? Are you sure your lookup value is in column A of Sheet1?)
4. A number is stored as text in one location but not the other.

Also, if it helps, note that you can use wildcards in Vlookups as well. The following is a valid formula to find the first row that has the word "test" anywhere in Column A of Sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP("*test*",Sheet1!A:B:,2,0)
```